# Convert JSON to Elements tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'd like to turn JSON (Object literal) into Elements tree HTML.
I want to also support custom `data-*` attributes like i.e: `data-example`, `data-link` etc.

Example of my JSON:

```
{"<>":"div","content":["hello",{"<>":"span","content":["Hello"],"attrs":{"class":"color-red"}}],"attrs":{"class":"flex"}}
```

And now this is the output I expect :

```
<div class='flex'>hello<span class='color-red'>Hello</span></div>
```

I'm not sure where to start with that problem...

Comment: Could you show what have you tried? Please read [ask], and [edit] with a [mcve] of your best code that expresses the research you've done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JSON to HTML Elements tree

Basically, the key is to use a recursive function.

- Modify slightly your initial JSON to remove strange properties like `"<>"`, use rather `"tag"`.
- Create **two helper functions** `newEL` and `newTN` to generate new Element with attributes or Text Node accordingly
- Create a **recursive function** `JSON2DF` that will parse your JSON (or Object) data into a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) container which can be later [appended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) wherever is needed.
- If an iterating object has a `content` array - **call recursively** `JSON2DOM` **on every element** in the array.

```js
const newTN = (text) => document.createTextNode(text);
const newEL = (tag, attr) => {
  const EL = document.createElement(tag);
  if (attr) Object.entries(attr).forEach(([k,v]) => EL.setAttribute(k, v));
  return EL;
};

const JSON2DF = (data, PAR = new DocumentFragment()) => {
  const CH = typeof data === "string" ? newTN(data) : newEL(data.tag, data.attr)
  if (data.content) data.content.forEach(d => JSON2DF(d, CH)); // Recursion!
  PAR.append(CH);
  return PAR;
};

const data = {
  tag: "DIV",
  attr: { class: "flex" },
  content: [
    "Some DIV text",
    {
      tag: "SPAN",
      attr: { class: "color-red", "data-test": "test" },
      content: [
        "Some span text",
      ],
    }
  ],
};

document.body.append(JSON2DF(data));
```

```css
.color-red { color: red; }
```

The result is as expected:

```
<div class="flex">
  Some DIV text<span class="color-red">Some span text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me and I wish you success :)

Comment: your code works but attributes like (data-example, data-link) Does not support :(

Comment: @SalarIzadi in such case you could expand the `newEL` function to account for `"data-*"` and use `EL.setAttribute` inside a `forEach` loop on that new Element

Comment: If possible, edit the code you sent me. Thank you. please

Comment: @SalarIzadi edited the code and fixed to support custom `data-*` attributes. When using attributes instead of node properties - use `"class"` (instead of `"className"`) as you initially did.

Comment: Thank you bro for helping me so much. I wish you success :)