# Create HTML Element using jQuery dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to create an HTML element in JS using jQuery from an Array of Objects have information of element tag, class, and other attributes or style.

###### Why Use jQuery instead HTML?

You can think of sort of dynamically append small components like buttons, inputs at certain place in html. This helps user to interact with webpage better.

##### **Code**

```
let array = [{el:'div',class:'card',attr:{id:'abc'},css:{display:'block'}}];
let array2 = [{el:'div'}]
const element = (array) => {
    let el = [];
    Object.values(array).forEach((val)=>{
      el.push($(`<${val.el}>`).addClass(val.class).attr(val.attr).css(val.css))
    })
    return el;
}
element(array) // Works fine;
element(array2) //Throws error because we are not feeding any value to .addClass ...
```

it works fine when all keys are available in the array but it doesn't work when any of them missing.

> Error >
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined

how do I fix this? thanks

Comment: `array` is a syntax error. Please fix your example.

Comment: _"ignore typo"_ - No. Fix them.

Comment: The script in your question doesn't throw the mentioned error (after fixing the syntax error): https://jsfiddle.net/ycs8k05r/

Comment: @Andreas try with this ```array = [{el:'div'}]``` you will get error. I have tested it with propper array syntax.

Comment: Yes, with that I will get an error. But not the one mentioned in your question. Please fix your question so that it, a) works at all and b) throws the error you've mentioned

Comment: Still not the error you've mentioned in your question (but at least we now have an error at all): https://jsfiddle.net/okb7Ls3h/

Comment: You don't need that Array at all since you only use it for **one single object** - instead of `[{}]` why don't you use simply `{}`?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Ok, then I have to write a long if-else logic. I already have a long version of this function I just want to make it shot.

Comment: @Andreas ```jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined
    at S.fn.init.attr (VM969 jquery.min.js:2)
    at $ (VM969 jquery.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.attr (VM969 jquery.min.js:2)
    at <anonymous>:6:52
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at element (<anonymous>:5:26)
    at <anonymous>:11:1``` this will throw in your chrome DevTools console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to decouple the tagName *`el`* from the other Object data and return *that* jQuery Element instance Object `$`:

```js
const $element = ({el, ...rest}) => $(`<${el}/>`, rest);

const el1 = {el:'div', class:'card', id:'abc', text:"Hello", css:{color:'red'}, appendTo: "body"};
const el2 = {el:'span', class:'test', text:" World!", css:{color:'blue'}, appendTo: "body"};

const $el1 = $element(el1);
const $el2 = $element(el2);

$el1.css({fontSize: "2em"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

From the [DOCS](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/)

> As of jQuery 1.8, any jQuery instance method (a method of jQuery.fn) can be used as a property of the object passed to the second parameter:

```js
$("<tagName/>", {properties})
```

For an Array of data, here's how to return an Array of jQuery instances by simply passing the function $element as the `Array.prototype.map()` argument:

```js
const $element = ({el, ...rest}) => $(`<${el}/>`, rest);

const els = [
  {el:'div', class:'card', id:'abc', text:"Hello", css:{color:'red'}, appendTo: "body"},
  {el:'span', class:'test', text:" World!", css:{color:'blue'}, appendTo: "body"}
];

const $els = els.map($element);
console.log($els);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank You @RokoC.Buljan; Problem is solved now. :)

Comment: I am trying to append child element to the $newElement; Here is my try can you tell me where I am doing wrong. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/290fa7ow/)

Comment: @ANOLGHOSH you need to recursively call the same function on that array collection - no matter how deep.

Comment: @ANOLGHOSH see this answer and its example: [Convert JSON to Elements tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67291331/383904)

Comment: Okey [Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/290fa7ow/5) It's working now, with an ignorable issue, I hope you will check my code and guide me.

Answer (score -2):

> You have written the wrong syntax to access object item values. try below-mentioned code to access object values directly

```
let stringfyObject=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
       
el.push((`<${stringfyObject.el}>`).addClass(stringfyObject.class).attr(stringfyObject.attr).css(stringfyObject.css));
```

Comment: what if the array contains more than one element?

Comment: Why "clone" the array with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`? What does this change?

Comment: The name of the variable `stringifyObject` is not correct. Either its a string or an object. But definitely not both.

Comment: Author has edited it's first version of the code

Comment: @ANOLGHOSH In the first version of the shared source code contains an object not an array...